# Perform a series of outer products using tracedot in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

To perform an outer product between two vectors in Python (scipy/numpy) you can use the outer function, or you can simply use dot like this:

```
In [76]: dot(rand(2,1), rand(1,2))
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0.43427387,  0.5700558 ],
       [ 0.19121408,  0.2509999 ]])
```

Now the question is, suppose I have a list of vectors (or two lists...) and I want to calculate all the outer products, creating a list of square matrices. How do I do that easily? I believe tensordot is able to do that, but how?

Comment: If it the lists are huge, look at PyTables: http://www.pytables.org/moin

Comment: Do you need to compute the list of outer products, or just their sum (or some other property)?

Comment: @dividebyzero: Is `creating a list of square matrices` really your end goal? Could you be more specific what you are aiming for? Thanks

Comment: @Paulo They are not very large lists... Around 1000 elements. And what I am looking for is for the fastest and simplest way to calculate.

Comment: @Jeremiah I do need the list... What I am doing is calculating the so-called Structure Tensors from an image, over just a line of the image. It's a list of gradient vectors, and I need the outer product of each vector with itself. I will actually add some of them later, over the three image channels, and also with the top and bottom lines. But the result is still a list of 2x2 matrices, one for each pixel of the image line.

Comment: @eat As I just explained above to Jeremiah, this is really the goal. There will be additions eventually, but not a summation over every matrix like in a covariance matrix calculation. I am really working with lists of matrices. That's why we should be really talking about tensors instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third (and easiest to generalize) way to compute outer products is via broadcasting.

Some 3-vectors (vectors on rows):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(100, 3)
y = np.random.randn(100, 3)
```

Outer product:

```
from numpy import newaxis
xy = x[:,:,newaxis] * y[:,newaxis,:]

# 10th matrix
print xy[10]
print np.outer(x[10,:], y[10,:])
```

Comment: ...But I am still looking for a tensordot implementation in order to compare the speed!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer provided by pv. is not correct, as the resulting xy array would have shape (100,3,3).
The correct broadcasting is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import newaxis
x = np.random.randn(100, 3)
y = np.random.randn(100, 3)

xy =  x[:,newaxis, :,newaxis] * y[newaxis,:,newaxis,:]
```

The resulting xy array is now of shape (100,100,3,3) and contains cross products of all couples of 3-vectors in x and y:

```
for i,a in enumerate(x):
    for j,b in enumerate(y):
        if not np.alltrue(np.outer(a,b) == xy[i,j]): print("The code is wrong")
```

gives no output :)